# How to insert values in the unit test FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making unit tests in the registration form and I can not enter
values ​​in FormCollection .. as it had to do this test when you have the form collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can't add values to the FormCollection:

```
FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();
collection.Add("Name", "Value");
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the one from System.Web.Mvc, and not the one from the Owin namaspace.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what library you use to make tests. On my case i use NSubstitue on c# so:

```
private IFormCollection formCollection = Substitute.For<IFormCollection>();
private const int AmountOfFilesRequired = 3;
```

Then i declare the value that i want to return:

```
formCollection.Count.Returns(3);
someEntity.SetFiles(formCollection);
```

And finally do the assert:

```
Assert.That(someEntity.GetFiles().Count, Is.EqualTo(AmountOfFilesRequired));
```

I hope that my english is not an obstacle to understand my answer :D